# D3 V4 How to move dots according to zoom in linechart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Small problems are difficult to identify. I am using [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172) to create a linechart using d3 v4. I'm using **d3.line()** rather than **d3.area()**. Also drawing circles on the line peak points. Things are working fine.

Problem is with the drawn circles. They are not moving to the correct position when i'm zooming the graph.
Here is the complete code:

```css
.area {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #a2dced;
  stroke-width: 2;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.zoom {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

rect.selection
{
 fill:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script>
var data = [{date: "10:30:00", price: 36000},
   {date: "11:00:20", price: 40000},
   {date: "12:00:00", price: 38000},
   {date: "14:20:00", price: 50400}];
   
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 110, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = +svg.attr("height") - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S");//"%b %Y");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
    .on("brush end", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var area = d3.line()
 //.curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
 .x(function (d) {
  return x(d.date);
 })
 .y(function (d) {
  return y(d.price);
 });
    
var area2 = d3.line()
 .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
 .x(function (d) {
  return x2(d.date);
 })
 .y(function (d) {
  return y2(d.price);
 });
 

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

  function update(){ 
 
   for(var k in data)
  {
   type(data[k]);
  }   
   
   x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
   y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.price; })]);
   x2.domain(x.domain());
   y2.domain(y.domain());


      focus.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area);

   focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

   focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(yAxis);

   focus.selectAll("circle")                                    
    .data(data)                                         
    .enter().append("circle") 
    .attr("class","circle") 
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", 'orange')
    .style("stroke", 'red')
    .style("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.price); });
 
   context.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area2);

   context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
    .call(xAxis2);
 
   context.selectAll("circle")                                    
    .data(data)                                         
    .enter().append("circle") 
    .attr("class","circle") 
    .attr("r", 1)
    .style("fill", 'blue')
    .style("stroke", 'red')
    .style("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.price); }); 

   context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, x.range());

   svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);
}



function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  
  focus.selectAll('.circle').attr("transform", function(d) { 
 return "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.price) + ")"; 
  });
  
  

  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}

function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  
  focus.selectAll('.circle').attr("transform", function(d) { 
 return "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.price) + ")"; 
  });
  
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
  context.selectAll('.circle').attr("transform", function(d) { 
 return "translate(" + x2(d.date) + "," + y2(d.price) + ")"; 
  });
}

function type(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.price = +d.price;
  return d;
}
update();
</script>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwr089p7/)** link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated you [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwr089p7/1/) by replacing all `transform`attributes by changing it to `cx` and `cy`, e.g.:

*before*

```
focus.selectAll('.circle').attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.price) + ")"; 
  });
```

*after*

```
focus.selectAll('.circle')
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date) })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.price); });
```

Otherwise, you will translate with your other coordinates, which might lead to hard to find problems

Comment: Thanks for the solution Mr. Hugues, but it's not completed. 'context' circles are not moving even after applying 'translation'

Comment: Ok i got it sorry! 'cx' 'cy' is should be from X2 and Y2. Now it's working fine. Thanks again!